# Why the next line is not being covered in unit test coverage?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I running jasmin-Karma test for the below function

```
ExampleFunction(someParam) {
    let element = document.querySelector(`aSelectorId}`);
    if (element ) {
      element.classList.remove('disabled');
      element.classList.add('enabled');
    }
  }
```

Here is test I run

```
 describe('ExampleFunction', () => {
    it('it should enable and disable', () => {
      spyOn(document, "querySelector").and.callFake(function() {
        return {
              value: true
          }
      });
      componentInstance.ExampleFunction("params");
      expect(componentInstance.Somevalue).toBe(something);
    });
  });
```

Now the issue is the code coverage shows

```
 element.classList.remove('disabled');
```

as covered but not this line!

```
  element.classList.add('enabled');
```

Can you all please tell me why its happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value you are specifying inside your spy does not have a classList property. That should result in the last line of code not being executed.

Try adding two a remove and add method into your spy:

```
return {
  value: true
  classList: {
    remove: () => {},
    add: () => {}
  }         
}
```

Alternatively you could also provide mocks for remove and add, so that you can test that the methods are being called with the right property, too.

This could look something along those lines:

```
    it('it should enable and disable', () => {
      const removeSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
      const addSpy = jasmine.createSpy();

      spyOn(document, "querySelector").and.callFake(function() {
        return {
              value: true,
              classList: {
                 add: addSpy,
                 remove: removeSpy
              }
          }
      });
      componentInstance.ExampleFunction("params");
      expect(componentInstance.Somevalue).toBe(something);
      expect(addSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('enabled');
      expect(removeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('disabled')
    });
```

Note this is pseudo code, I didn't get to test it properly but it should work along those lines.

Have a look at the [jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/jasmine.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please tell me about mocs of add and remove?

Comment: Try jasmine.createSpy. Have a look into my updated answer. It's purely pseudo code, so you might need to do some changes, but it should show you the general idea

Comment: Sure , I just missed out that :)

Comment: Hey @Erbsenkoenig , I am facing some issue again, can you help me please?

Comment: I can have a look. Can you share a link to the question?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151027/jasmin-unit-test-cases-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-classlist-of

Comment: sir I am facing this issue since last 3 days!